# How do I render the selected value just below the select control?

Tags: reactjs

We are using a multiple select control from react-select. When we select a value from the select box, it displays inside the select box. Can we display the selected value in another control below the select box?

```
render() {
  console.log("this.state", this.state);
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 select-box">
      <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 ">
        <Select
          multi={true}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={this.state.labelData}
          onInputKeyDown={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: yes you can, just put the input value in the wrapping compo's state and display it somewhere else.

Comment: render() {
        console.log("this.state",this.state)
        return (
            <div>
                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 select-box" >
                       
                        <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 ">
                       
                        <Select  options={this.state.labelData} multi={true}  onChange={this.handleChange} onInputKeyDown={this.handleChange}  >   </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a component with state, you can save the value in your state and show it any way you want:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: null }
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
  }
  handleSelect(evt) {
    this.setState({value: evt.currentTarget.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <select onChange={this.handleSelect}>
         <option>...</option>
         <option>...</option>
         <option>...</option>
        </select>
     {this.state.value && `The selected value is ${this.state.value}`}
     </div>)
  }
}
```